# What is the shiur for a min in Mishloach Manos

Tags: rambam, purim, mishloach-manot

What is the minimum shiur for a min in mishloach manos, and, particularly according to the Rambam ([פרק ב הלכה ט"ו](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah,_Scroll_of_Esther_and_Hanukkah.2?lang=he)) who holds that you can give 2 of the same thing, what's the shiur to say that you can divide it in half? (And I'm not just asking for the ערוך השלחן who doesn't hold of cutting one min in half, or even having 2 identical minim)

Comment: Who ever disagreed that they can both be the same Bracha?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/two-minim-for-mishloach-manos

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6325/where-did-the-different-bracha-for-mishloach-manos-idea-come-from

Comment: "... _according to the Rambam (פרק ב הלכה ט"ו) who holds that you can give 2 of the same thing_ ...". Can you please quote (preferably in the question) where the Rambam explicitly says that both _Manot_ can be of the same thing? I only see him saying (in [the _Halakhah_ you cite](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah,_Scroll_of_Esther_and_Hanukkah.2.15?lang=bi)) "And similarly a a person is obligated to send two portions of meat or two **types** of cooked food or two **types** of food to his friend".

Answer (score 1):

R Binyanim Tabadi was asked that question and answered that the objective of *mishloach manot* is to "spread love" between Jews. Therefore the *manot* need to awaken love between the specific sender and specific recipient.

He brings the Chaye Adam (כלל קנה סל"ה) who writes that a wealthy person who gives to a poor, or vice versa, should both be stringent with themselves and give nice portions "according to the higher between themselves". As such the wealthy person should give something according to his stature, and the poor person according to the stature of the wealthy person. The Biur Halacha (תרצה, ד) brings the Chaye Adam and writes it is good to do this *lechatchila*.

R Tabadi writes that he heard directly from R [Mordechai Eliyahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Eliyahu) that the *manot* should ideally be *ochel mamash* and not sweets. He brings the [same Rambam that you quote](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Scroll_of_Esther_and_Hanukkah.2.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who connects *mishloach manot* with the dishes served at the *mishte*, and suggests the *manot* should be worthy of being served there.

So on the specific quantity, whatever it is that is according to your stature, the one of the recipient and will be fit to serve on his/her table.

Comment: While this, similar to the ritva, seems to say that the shiur is based on the person's chashivus, my question was if there is a shiur at all for a min, or if it depends on the food and recipient - and if there is a shiur for cutting it in half which is different than just double the base shiur

Comment: "_He brings the same Rambam that you quote who connects mishloach manot with the dishes served at the mishte_ ...". That is, according to the printed editions, which group them into one _Halakhah_. In the Mechon Mamre edition, they are [separate _Halakhot_](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3a02.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The [Tzitz Eliezer 14:65](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14513#p=132&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) discusses this question and answers that one would need the size of three eggs per mana.