# Mishloach Manot food to decor ratio

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot

In the last years more and more money and effort are put on the decor of the M"M relatively to the actual food.

I was wondering if any sources mention a sort of the "final ratio" of food to decor, where there's so much decor or it is so expensive it makes the food secondary or negligible and males the M"M "non-Kosher"?

For example, it becomes very popular here in Israel especially when sent to Rebbis and VIPs, to have a huge and expensive tray, usually silver or glass maybe even with candlesticks or electric appliances and on top of it a couple of cheap cookies and a bunch of chocolate candies.

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90008/11501

Comment: הידור מצוה עד שליש